# Почему в одном случае функция не сохраняет переменную, а в другом сохраняет

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    let shooter = function() { // функция shooter
      alert( i ); // должна выводить порядковый номер
    };
    shooters.push(shooter);
    i++;
  }

  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // у 0-го стрелка будет номер 10
army[5](); // и у 5-го стрелка тоже будет номер 10
// ... у всех стрелков будет номер 10, вместо 0, 1, 2, 3.
```

```js
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    let j = i;
    let shooter = function() { // функция shooter
      alert( j ); // должна выводить порядковый номер
    };
    shooters.push(shooter);
    i++;
  }

  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[5](); // 5
```

Почему в первом случае переменная i не сохраняется, а во втором просто присваивая она сохраняется.  Т.е while создаёт каждой функции свое другое лексическое окружение?

Comment: Это полный дубликат. Не важно как вызывается функция. Главное что она вызывается не сразу в момент объявления.

Answer (score -2):

Всё легко, в первым случае, вы дальше увеличиваете `i`, которая в итоге становиться 10-кой. А `shooter` до сих пор выводит `i`, а не текущее число. Можно увидеть это в подобном примере:

Во втором случае же, вы сохраняете текущее число в переменную, теперь получается что `shooter`, выводит так нужное число (то, которые вы сохранили в `j`).

Можно от этого избавиться использовав обычный `for` цикл:

```js
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let shooter = function() { // функция shooter
      alert( i ); // должна выводить порядковый номер
    };
    shooters.push(shooter);
  }

  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[5](); // 5
```

Comment: Т.е while в каждом цикле отдельно свои переменные в отдельных лексических видимостях хранит? Например, во втором случае, когда вводится army[0]() вызывается функция, которая возвращает j, но откуда она знает, что это именно та j? Т.е каждый цикл создаёт свою среду?

Comment: Т.е получается в первом случае т.к переменная объявлена выше, она никак не будет относится к этой локальной области? Т.е там i это ссылка на переменную, которая стала уже в конце цикла 10, поэтому все функции ссылаются на одну и ту же переменную которая не в их локальной области видимости?

Comment: @hodini если я вас правильно понял, то да. `i` в первом случае объявлена для функций которые ниже "глобально", а они сами просто ссылаются на неё, что и приводит вас, к вашей проблеме.